# BLOB in Database is always EMPTY

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I want to store a file containing CalDAV instructions which is stored on the filesystem into the database to use it with SabreDAV. The following code snippet creates the file which works fine:

```
$datei = fopen("./calendar/temp/tmp_event".$eventrand,"w");
$caldavcontent = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR[...]";
fwrite($datei, $caldavcontent,2000);
fclose($datei);
```

The following code snippet reads the file (which contains the data as required, I already checked that) and should store it into the database:

```
$blob = fopen("./calendar/temp/tmp_event".$eventrand,'rb');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO calendarobjects(calendardata,lastmodified,[...])
VALUES(?,".time().",[...]");
$stmt->bind_param("b",$blob);
$stmt->execute();
```

The query is executed by the system without any error but the BLOB that should be stored into the database remains empty. Does anybody have an idea about whats wrong?

Thank you very very much in advance!

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$blob` variable contains a handle to the file, not the binary content.

Add the following lines to read the data into a variable:

```
$blob = fopen("./calendar/temp/tmp_event".$eventrand,'rb');

$fsize = filesize("./calendar/temp/tmp_event".$eventrand); 
$contents = fread($blob, $fsize); fclose($blob);


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO calendarobjects(calendardata,lastmodified,[...])
VALUES(?,".time().",[...]");
$stmt->bind_param("b",$contents);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: If you're going to read the whole file, why not `file_get_contents`? Is it not binary-safe? Also, don't forget to `fclose` the file...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! @Mihail Burduja: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. The file will be read correctly. It leads definitely to a working solution, but it seems like there is another problem with the transmission of the file to the database. The blob remains empty in the database. Meanwhile I tried it with (1) MYSQL LOAD_FILE (I already checked permissions) which makes the value of calendardata becomes NULL (perhabs the "infamous linux bug" I stumbled uppon?) and (2) file_get_contents where the Object in the database remains empty.

Thank you very much

Comment: @DrFeelgood Try binding the blob as string. There is a known problem with 'b' type setting the value to null. So try $stmt->bind_param("s",$contents); instead of $stmt->bind_param("b",$contents);. Source:  http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#96850

Comment: @Mihail Burduja: You are the best!! Thank you so very much for your great support! May I give you a little present for all you have done? I would be very happy if you could send me your PayPal Address or any alternatives to make that possible. My email address is collector@null.net. I'm deeply indebted to you. Thanks a ton and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation. `fopen` doesn't give you the file contents. It opens a file and gives you a handle to work with that file. You need to use that handle to actually read some data from the file.